# Angular 2 CLI environment set up

Tags: angular, environment

I want to set up development, test(QA) and PROD environment for my Angular 2 project.
While going for QA env set up `ng build --environment=qa`

I am getting below error

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at createSourceFile (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15457:109)
>       at parseSourceFileWorker (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15389:26)
>       at Object.parseSourceFile (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15338:26)
>       at Object.createSourceFile (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15192:29)
>       at VirtualFileStats.getSourceFile (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:66:35)
>       at WebpackCompilerHost.getSourceFile (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:213:38)
>       at findSourceFile (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67909:29)
>       at processImportedModules (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:68056:25)
>       at findSourceFile (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67937:17)
>       at processSourceFile (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67840:27)
>       at processRootFile (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67728:13)
>       at D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67018:60
>       at Object.forEach (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:1449:30)
>       at Object.createProgram (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:67018:16)
>       at AotPlugin._setupOptions (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:129:28)
>       at new AotPlugin (D:\ECC Web\ECC WEB\working\8-Aug\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:26:14)

Below is my code for environment set up
in angular-cli.json

```
"environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "qa": "environments/environment.qa.ts"
      }
```

in environments/environment.qa.ts

```
export const environment = {
    production: false
  };
```

Comment: Do you have the same variables in your other environment.ts files? Also, are you certain the file name in your angular-cli.json matches the actual file name?

Comment: As @EvanM suggested, check the names of your `environment.*.ts` files and the config under `environments` in `.angular-cli.json`. In my case, it was just a typo: `envrionment.qa.ts` instead of `environment.qa.ts`.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript probably wants to read a source file that doesn't exist. The stack trace doesn't mention the name of the missing file, but you can get it by editing the file `node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js` - add a log statement `console.log(fileName);` at the beginning of the `createSourceFile` method and run the build command again. The last filename before the error should be the one causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks it was environment file.

Comment: @Akanksha, you could consider accepting the answer so others know that you have solved the problem and the author gets some points.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that,we set envName in  **environments/environment.qa.ts**

```
export const environment = {  
        production: false,
        envName: 'qa'
 };
```

can you try this refer this doc [angular-cli-using-the-environment-option](http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/)

Comment: Thanks Robert.I have tried this doc but QA environment is not setting up.